# Error -999 when loading multiple webViews

Tags: html, ios, url, uiwebview

The iOS app I am making can have multiple webViews loading the same url at the same time. Resulting in this error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x176b7bc0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://example.com, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://example.com}
```

I read this happens when a new request is started before the old request has been completed. How do I prevent this from happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent weeks worrying about this error. I was getting it randomly while accessing web pages. In my case I put it down to pages being requested too quickly back to back as the web access was driven by a state machine in code and not by a user.

After much searching, in the end I found a few discussions which could not explain why the error was occuring, but it was felt that it was feature of UIWebView rather than something you should worry about. The guidance was to ignore it. I will see if I can find the article and update this answer later if I can find it.

I updated my code as follows, and so far have seen no ill effects at all since adding it. This would suggest it is almost a notification and anything which causes it seems to get corrected inside UIWebView. Hopefully this is the same in your case.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    VSSLog(@"Entry: error = %@",error);

    // Added this based on net advice. Its a bogus error.
    if ([error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled) {
        return;
    }

    ... Normal error handling code for proper errors.
}
```

I am not one for out of sight out of mind, but this I believe is one of those cases where it is ok.

Finally if you are using iOS8 only, you could try moving to use the new WKWebView rather than UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

Use the delegate methods. Determine which view fired the method then fire the next if you're looking to run them sequentially.

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview{
     if ( webview == self.wView1 )
     {
          // stuff
     } else if ( webview == self.wView2 ) {
          // stuff 2
     }
}
```

[UITableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

Comment: So this would mean I would use the same delegate for both the views? the containerview my webView is in is the delegate right now and I create multiple instances of that view.

Comment: Yes, you can assign the delegate to the same controller and handle multiple views.

Comment: But why would I do it in the webViewDidFinishLoad? That wouldn't be called if the webView never finishes the loading right? It just calls: didFailLoadWithError

Comment: You can use any of the delegate methods. That was just a single example of using the same function for multiple views. There are more delegate functions for a UIWebView such as didStart, etc. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html